# How store order and products in a database?

Tags: database

I have an order with details such customer id, order date, order type etc...

The order then contains a list of products on that order

Do I create one table for the order and then another table for the products?

If so, should there then be foreign keys between the 2 tables?

Comment: Yes, a normalized database would have separate relations for customer, order, item, and product.

Comment: Thanks. Which way would the foreign key work? Should there be one from products to orders and one from orders to products?

Comment: Yes, product table contains the detail of product, and Order table will contain customer_id and product_Id, and this is normal easy practicing work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I'd model it:

1. Customer can have many Orders; an Order belongs to one Customer.
2. An Item refers to one Product
3. An Order can have many Items; an Item belongs to one Order.

One-to-many foreign keys always belong in the "many" table and refer back to their "one" table.

If you have many to many relationships you need a JOIN table, which has two one-to-many foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure should look like below. In your `product` table create a reference to `order_id` in `order` table by means of foriegn key. Thatway, each order will be associated
with one or more products and you can find out the same using a `JOIN` in your `SELECT` query.

```
Table: Order(order_id Primary key,customer id, order date, order type)

Table: Products(product_id primary key, order_id foriegn key,col1, col2);
```

Explanation:

A product may not be associated with a order at all time but a order must be associated with a product (Obhious reason, we can't have a blank order).

Comment: So no need to have a foreign key in the orders table referencing the products table?

Comment: Yes, that's what it should be. I edited the answer. I wrote it opposite. Check now.

Comment: Is that right? doesn't  the foreign key belong in the many table?

Comment: @totalitarian, I think you are bit confused. You will define the Fk in one table which will refer to other table. Not sure what you mean by ` foreign key belong in the many table`?

Comment: By many table, I mean the products table, Eg, one order can have many products, but each product can only have one order. In this scenario, I believe the foreign key should be defined in the products table like you did originally

Answer (score 1):

You current condition may works if the product is not belong to your store/source , you are getting products from different source and client order the product so you can maintain the order with  the require details.
if the product came from your source/store then you must need the product and order